# Keys from functional dependencies

Tags: database

If we have functional dependencies ABC->DE and D->AB, one key is obviously ABC, but is CDE also a key?

If CDE is a key, then all 5 attributes are prime, and thus is the relation in 2NF and 3NF as well?

edit: there are only ABCDE in the relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDE is a superkey, a key is CD wich is enough to determine all the other elements:

```
CD+ = CD
    = CDAB (since CD → AB)
    = CDABE (since ABC → E)
```

So the prime attributes are ABCD, and the relation is in 3NF, since the dependency D → AB has only prime attributes on the right side, while it is not in BCNF (since D is not a (super)key).